# How to calculate the interaction standard error of a linear regression model in R?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, interpretation

I have the following model and want to make a table with the interpretation of the interaction effects as suggested by Bambor and Clark in [this paper](http://pan.oxfordjournals.org/content/14/1/63.full.pdf+html). However, I have no idea on how to calculate the $cov(\hat{\beta_1}, \hat{\beta_5})$ in the formula.

The model:

```
reg <- lm( log(Y) ~ as.factor(X1) +  as.factor(X2) + log(as.numeric(X3)) + log(as.numeric(X4)) + as.factor(X1)*as.factor(X2), data=DB)
```

The results:

```
Residuals:
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -5.1091 -0.3036  0.0294  0.3396  3.6537 

Coefficients:
                                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                     -0.08848    0.09523  -0.929   0.3531    
as.factor(X1)1                                  -0.12795    0.06227  -2.055   0.0402 *  
as.factor(X2)1                                   0.05666    0.06694   0.846   0.3976    
log(as.numeric(X3))                              0.03602    0.02121   1.699   0.0898 .  
log(as.numeric(X4))                              0.97546    0.02671  36.514   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(X1)1:as.factor(X2)1                    0.10733    0.11790   0.910   0.3629    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.6729 on 795 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9161, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9155 
F-statistic:  1735 on 5 and 795 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The formula:

$\sqrt{var(\hat{\beta_1}) + var(\hat{\beta_5}) +  2cov(\hat{\beta_1}\hat{\beta_5})}$

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't fully answer your question.  $cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)$ would be the entry in the matrix with column name, in your case, `as.factor(X1)1` row name `as.factor(X2)1`, assuming what you wished to find the covariance for were the coefficients with values -0.12795 and 0.05666, and similarly for the other covariances.

Comment: Thanks @jbowman, I think now I understand! I must use 0.00340945299? Ok?I just added the covariance matrix to the question.

Comment: Yes, you have got it!

Comment: @jbowman, why don't you convert your comments into an answer (since that's what they are)? Then the OP can accept it, & I can upvote it.

Comment: It also happens to be wrong... I didn't realize that `summary(reg)$cov` gave an unscaled covariance matrix.  I'll post the correct answer in a minute or two.

Comment: Deleting my erroneous comment to avoid causing confusion... and posting this note to clarify why the comment thread may be incomprehensible afterwards.

Comment: I also edited the question to avoid confusion. Thanks @jbowman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need a little more information than `summary(reg)` provides, namely, the covariance matrix of the estimates.  `vcov(reg)` will give that to you:

```
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- 0.7*rnorm(100) + 0.7*x1
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(100)

reg <- lm(y~x1+x2)
vcov(reg)
             (Intercept)           x1           x2
(Intercept)  0.009780556 -0.002229766  0.001652152
x1          -0.002229766  0.016996594 -0.012423096
x2           0.001652152 -0.012423096  0.018662900
```

The covariance between the coefficient of `x1` and `x2` is in the cell with row label `x1` and column label `x2` (or vice versa), and the variance terms are on the diagonal.

The difference between `vcov(reg)` and `summary(reg)$cov` is that the latter is not scaled by $\hat{\sigma}^2$.