# Standard errors and p-values for interaction effects with GLM

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, p-value, interaction, standard-error

I’m wondering how to calculate the standard errors and p-values of interaction effects in logistic models.

For illustration, consider this toy example, where we think some treatment effect will differ between men and women (but not by education):

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 2000
dv <- sample(0:1,n,rep=TRUE)
condition <- sample(c("control","treat"),n,rep=TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("male","female"),n,rep=TRUE)
education <- sample(c("less_than_undergrad","undergrad","post_grad"),n,rep=TRUE)

m <- glm(dv ~ condition +
             gender +
             education +
             condition:gender,
           family = "binomial")
```

Which gives us this:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)               -0.07849    0.11065  -0.709   0.4781  
conditiontreat             0.22031    0.12658   1.740   0.0818 .
gendermale                -0.04788    0.12558  -0.381   0.7030  
educationpost_grad         0.02815    0.10965   0.257   0.7974  
educationundergrad         0.04922    0.10981   0.448   0.6540  
conditiontreat:gendermale -0.13205    0.17921  -0.737   0.4612  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here, the treatment effect for `female` (the reference category) is estimated at `0.22031`, with an SE of `0.12658` and a p-value of `0.0818`.

The treatment effect for `male`, by contrast, would be

```
beta <- 0.22031 - 0.13205 # 0.08826
```

**But what is the SE and p-value for that estimate?** I believe it's not the ones given on the final row of the output, since they speak to the *difference* in effect between `male` and `female`.

**1. Calculating the SE**
From [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33260/how-to-calculate-the-interaction-standard-error-of-a-linear-regression-model-in) and [this](https://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2017/05/17/adding-standard-errors-for-interaction-terms/), I gather that the SE should instead be calculated as follows:

$\sqrt{var(\hat{\beta_1}) + var(\hat{\beta_5}) +  2*cov(\hat{\beta_1}\hat{\beta_5})}$

Applied to the case above, that would give us the following

```
beta_se <- sqrt(vcov(m)[2,2] + vcov(m)[6,6] + 2*vcov(m)[2,6]) # 0.1268722
```

**2. Calculating the p-value**
Once I have the SE, I gather from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/237076) that I would then simply calculate the p-value like this:

```
pnorm(-abs(beta)/beta_se) * 2 # 0.4866415
```

Have I understood all of this correctly?

---

**EDIT: Full code in one block:**

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 2000
dv <- sample(0:1,n,rep=TRUE)
condition <- sample(c("control","treat"),n,rep=TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("male","female"),n,rep=TRUE)
education <- sample(c("less_than_undergrad","undergrad","post_grad"),n,rep=TRUE)

m <- glm(dv ~ condition +
           gender +
           education +
           condition:gender,
         family = "binomial")
summary(m)

beta <- 0.22031 - 0.13205 # 0.08826
beta_se <- sqrt(vcov(m)[2,2] + vcov(m)[6,6] + 2*vcov(m)[2,6]) # 0.1268722
pnorm(-abs(beta)/beta_se) * 2 # 0.4866415

library(multcomp)
summary(glht(m, linfct = c("conditiontreat + conditiontreat:gendermale = 0")))
```

Which gives:

```
     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: glm(formula = dv ~ condition + gender + education + condition:gender, 
    family = "binomial")

Linear Hypotheses:
                                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
conditiontreat + conditiontreat:gendermale == 0  0.08825    0.12687   0.696    0.487
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot replicate your estimates with the R code provided, but you can verify your manual calculations by testing the null that linear combination of two coefficients is zero:

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 2000
dv <- sample(0:1,n,rep=TRUE)
condition <- sample(c("control","treat"),n,rep=TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("male","female"),n,rep=TRUE)
education <- sample(c("less_than_undergrad","undergrad","post_grad"),n,rep=TRUE)

m <- glm(dv ~ condition +
           gender +
           education +
           condition:gender,
           family = "binomial")

write.dta(data, "~/Desktop/data.dta")
summary(m)

names(coef(m)) 
library(multcomp)
summary(glht(m, linfct = c("conditiontreat + conditiontreat:gendermale = 0")))
```

The last part yields:

```
Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: glm(formula = dv ~ condition + gender + education + condition:gender, 
    family = "binomial")

Linear Hypotheses:
                                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
conditiontreat + conditiontreat:gendermale == 0  -0.1838     0.1290  -1.425    0.154
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

This shows that while the effect of treatment on the log odds is negative for males, it is not statistically distinguishable from zero.

---

Here's the same calculation from first principles:

```
> (te <- m$coefficients["conditiontreat"] + m$coefficients["conditiontreat:gendermale"])        
conditiontreat 
    -0.1838191 
> (se_te <- sqrt(vcov(m)["conditiontreat","conditiontreat"] 
+               + vcov(m)["conditiontreat:gendermale","conditiontreat:gendermale"]
+               + 2*vcov(m)["conditiontreat","conditiontreat:gendermale"]))
[1] 0.1290362
> (pval <- pnorm(te/se_te)*2)
conditiontreat 
      0.154286
```

Comment: Thank you, Dimitriy! Three things: 

(1) Apologies! There was a typo in the p-value calculation. The code should now replicate.

(2) When I run `summary(glht(m, linfct = c("conditiontreat + conditiontreat:gendermale = 0")))` I don’t get an estimate of `-0.1838`. Instead I get the numbers I have in my manual calculations: an estimate of `0.08825` with an SE of `0.12687` and p-value of `0.487`. 

(3) Are you sure it should be -2*Cov()? From the Wikipedia page it looks like it should be +2 for Var(aX + bY). And the +2 calculation seems to yield the ‘correct’ SE, as given by (2) above.

Comment: I don't see any edits to the data simulation part, so I still can't replicate your estimates/coefficients. The change to the manual p-value calculation does not alter that fact and our numbers won't line up without that fix. In your case, $b<1$, so the $Var(aX-bY)$ formula applies. Could certainly be that we are missing something.

Comment: Can't figure out why it's not replicating. Have added full code block in original post, which should replicate on copy+paste, and yield a positive estimate.

Comment: I think you are right about the plus. I made a silly algebra mistake and have edited that out. I still can't get your numbers, but the calculations also work out for me. See the edit above. Not sure what's going wrong with R, but I do get the same estimates in Stata as in R on my end.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitriy. Very strange that we're not getting the same numbers. The only difference is that I'm not running `write.dta(data, "~/Desktop/data.dta")`. But at least we're both getting the `glht` and manual method to give the same results on our respective ends, which seems to confirm that the way I was calculating the SE and p-value in the original post seems to have been the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is over 2 years old, but I wanted to comment for anyone else who finds this post useful (as I did). The calculation of the treatment effect for `male` in this case should include not only the reference level for treatment, but also the effect of sex. In other words:

$$\beta_{male + treatment} = \beta_{male} + \beta_{treatment} + \beta_{male:treatment}$$ (in OP's original calculation, $\beta_{male}$ was missing).

Or, in terms of odds ratios:

$$OR_{male+treatment} = OR_{male}\times OR_{treatment}\times OR_{male:treatment}$$

This also affects the calculation of the SE, as you should include the variance and covariance of the interaction term in the equation, as below (for generic variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and their interaction term $X_{1:2}$):

$$SE(β_{1+2}) = \sqrt{var(β_1+β_2+β_{1:2})} = \sqrt{var(β_1) + var(β_2) + var(β_{1:2}) + 2[cov(β_1,β_2) + cov(β_1,β_{1:2}) + cov(β_2,β_{1:2})]}$$

In R:

```
beta_se <- sqrt(vcov(m)[1,1] + vcov(m)[2,2] + vcov(m)[3,3] + 2*(vcov(m)[1,2] + vcov(m)[1,3] + vcov(m)[2,3]))
```

Construction of 95% confidence intervals follows as:

$$\beta_{1+2} \pm 1.96\times SE $$

which can be converted to confidence intervals on the odds ratio by exponentiating them.